# How to remove default Button classes from material UI and use my own css class

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React and material UI. I am using material UI button and I want to remove default button classes (MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text makeStyles-buttonCss-3). I want to use only my class 'buttonCss'. Please can anyone help me to fix this.

My code is below -:

```
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import { Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import * as React from 'react';`enter code here`

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {`enter code here`
  maxWidth: "100vw",
  maxHeight: "100vh",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "flex-start",
  justifyContent: "space-evenly",
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
},
mybox: {
  width: 300,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.main,
  color: "white",
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  borderRadius: 4,
  boxShadow: theme.shadows[10]
},
buttonCss : {
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.dark
},
deafult: {
  color: 'red'
}
}));

// implementing button this way
<Button className={classes.buttonCss} >Submit</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to remove default classes to add your own CSS. You can add CSS to the Button with `sx` property.

```
<Button sx={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.success.dark }}>Submit</Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't remove the default class and then continue using MaterialUi, now just use the default html button .

If you want only to customise, now just use

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {background: "red}
});

export default () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return  <Button className={classes} >Submit</Button>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried as you mentioned it worked but My requirement is that I need to use Material UI button  only not html Button and use only my css class on that button. Right now default Three css classes are being attached. And those attached Css classes are overriding my css property. Please have look at my code above